# Hackerrank day 11 error on webpage but not on spyder

Tags: python-3.x, list

recently I made this code here for the Day 11 of Hackerrank 30 day coding challenge:

```
arr = [[1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,2,4,4,0],[0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,1,2,4,0]]
f=0
sumas = []
while f<(len(arr)-2):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(arr) - 2):        
          sumas.append((sum(arr[0+f][c:3+c]) + arr[1+f][1+c] + sum(arr[2+f][c:3+c])))
          c+=1
    f+=1
print(max(sumas))
```

It takes subarrays from "arr" and sum all the integers on it after that takes the maximum sum number from the subarrays.

When I run my code on spyder works fine but I am getting this error here while running on Hackerrank;

```
Error (stderr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(max(sumas))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: I executed your code on hackerrank and it worked.I answered it with a small change check it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the elements in the "I" shape follows this pattern

```
arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2]
```

so we can traverse through the complete array with this

```
for _ in range(6):
    arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

ans=[]    
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        su=arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2]
    ans.append(su)
print(max(ans))
```

Comment: Thanks ! That is actually how I solve that ! But still using the c and f values for iterate over n number of c and f !